# Problems with commands in a discord bot

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

The discord bot im writing properly recognizes one command, but ignores another

The bot is supposed to send a dm to a specified user, and handles this fine. However, the bot does not respond to the help command.

```java
    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onMessageRecived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        Member member = event.getMessage().getMentionedMembers().get(0);
        System.out.println("message recived");
        event.getAuthor().getName();
        event.getMessage().getContentDisplay();
        if (event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equals("!help")) {
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("!help: displays this messgae" +
                    "!love (@user): Sends a dm to specified user that says 'I love you' in one of 102 languages").queue();
        }
            if (event.getMessage().getContentRaw().toLowerCase().startsWith("!love")) {
                event.getChannel().sendMessage(member.getUser().getName() + " has been loved").queue();
```

The bot should output:

```
!help: Displays this message
!love (@user): Sends a dm to specified user that says 'I love you' in one of 102 languages
```

But doesn't output anything when prompted with !help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I notice that could be wrong in your sample is the spelling of your method name. It's called **received** and not **recived**. Note that the **Guild**MessageReceivedEvent is only triggered for messages that are received in a **guild**, if you use direct messages it will not be fired.

There are 2 ways JDA implements event handling you can choose from.

### InterfacedEventManager (default)

Documentation: [InterfacedEventManager](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/core/hooks/InterfacedEventManager.html), [ListenerAdapter](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/core/hooks/ListenerAdapter.html)

#### Creating a Listener Class

```
public class MessageListener extends ListenerAdapter {
    @Override // this is good practice, it fails compilation if the method doesn't overeride
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        // your code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Your method must have the same name, visibility, and parameters in order to properly override the definition from `ListenerAdapter`. The use of `@Override` ensures this by generating a compilation error if the override is ill-formed.

#### Register ListenerAdapter

```
JDABuilder builder = new JDABuilder(BOT_TOKEN);
builder.setEventManager(new InterfacedEventManager()); // this can be omitted, its the default
builder.addEventListener(new MessageListener());
JDA api = builder.build();
```

It is required that every listener implements the `EventListener` interface for this event manager. This is done transitively by `ListenerAdapter`.

---

### AnnotatedEventManager

Documentation: [AnnotatedEventManager](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/core/hooks/AnnotatedEventManager.html), [SubscribeEvent](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/core/hooks/SubscribeEvent.html)

#### Creating a Listener Method

```
public class MessageSubscriber {
    @SubscribeEvent // required annotation
    public void onMessage(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        // your code here
    }

    @SubscribeEvent // required annotation
    public void onGuildMessage(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

You can add the `@SubscribeEvent` annotation on member methods and class methods (static methods).

#### Register Subscriber

```
JDABuilder builder = new JDABuilder(BOT_TOKEN);
builder.setEventManager(new AnnotatedEventManager());
builder.addEventListener(new MessageSubscriber());
JDA api = builder.build();
```

If you annotated class methods you can simply use `addEventListener(MessageSubscriber.class)`, for member methods it has to be a new instance `new MessageSubscriber()`!

---

If this doesn't answer your question you probably have some problem that cannot be interpreted from your current question. Please limit it to a specific problem by debugging your code and creating a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).